# How to set default background color for JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I've already searched all over the net, and tried several things, to try to set the default background color for `JTextPane`, but it still shows the default white color.

I'm trying to simulate console output, and I need the whole background to
be black, even if there is no text.

Seems like `setCharacterAttributes()` and `setParagraphAttributes()` only deal with
any inserted text, but the rest of the background is still the default white.

I saw something about maybe a bug related to setting the background color.

How can I do it?

It's plain text, not any HTML.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I finally found something that worked.

Using setBackground(Color.BLACK) would only set the background
under any inserted text, but the rest of the JTextPane's background was still
the default white, on my Windows machine.

I started to look at changing the UIDefault and that did it!
Here's what I used:

```
UIDefaults defs = UIManager.getDefaults();
defs.put("TextPane.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.BLACK));
defs.put("TextPane.inactiveBackground", new ColorUIResource(Color.BLACK));
```

And when it starts, with no text, the whole JTextPane is now black the way I want it
and any inserted text is the way I needed it to be.

Everything else I tried left the rest of the JTextPane white, and I tried
lots of different "solutions".

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: I've never had a problem using JDK4/5/6/7 on Windows 7. Post your SSCCE that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Have you tried using setBackground?

Answer (score 4):

Try this SSCCE. It demonstrates setting the background color on a JTextPane.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

/**
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435181/how-to-set-default-background-color-for-jtextpane
 */
public class Q19435181 {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example setting background color on JTextPane");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
        pane.add(blackJTextPane());
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }

      private Component blackJTextPane() {
        JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
        pane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        pane.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        pane.setText("Here is example text");
        return pane;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using system defaults, it is also possible to do it per specific item.
Here is the code I am using, based heavily on your notes:

```java
        Color bgColor = Color.BLACK;
        UIDefaults defaults = new UIDefaults();
        defaults.put("TextPane.background", new ColorUIResource(bgColor));
        defaults.put("TextPane[Enabled].backgroundPainter", bgColor);
        out.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", defaults);
        out.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", true);
        out.setBackground(bgColor);
```